# Return numbers from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In PHP how can I determine if a zip code exists within a string, and if so, return the zip code. In this context, a zip code can be either a string of 5 numbers (ie "55543") or a string of 5 numbers connected to 4 more numbers with a hyphen (ie "74657-9993")..

Can anyone help me out with a Regex pattern I can use with `preg_match` or any other good ways of doing this?

I have `preg_match_all("/\d{5}/", $str, $matches);` so far, but that doesn't account for the possible second 4 digits or the hyphen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 number connected to 4 more numbers with a hyphen:

```
preg_match_all("/\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b/", $str, $matches);
```

`(?:-\d{4,})?` is an optional group, with a hyphen, and at least 4 digits after it.

Edit: Forgot to prevent longer than 5 digits for the first part (and 4 digits for the second part), using a word boundary.

EDIT2:

Okay, something else I just noticed is that if you have `12345-12345` but don't want to get *any* number form this, you would use:

```
preg_match_all("/\b\d{5}(?!-\d{1,3}\b|-\d{5})(?:-\d{4})?\b/", $str, $matches);
```

The negative lookahead prevents the match of `-12345` (or more digits, or less than 4 digits) if present, but allow only 4 digits ahead.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dK0uI3)

Comment: it is about 4 more.. not 4 or more. `12345-12345` is not a valid zip code. a valid zip code is either `12345` or `12345-1234`

Comment: compare `your` http://jsfiddle.net/3W7YP/ with `mine` http://jsfiddle.net/3W7YP/2/

Comment: and your regex will also return true when user will enter `12345-`

Comment: @zzlalani Okay, I think that's a bit harsh now. The regex never accepted `12345-` and yours matches a zip code only if it's alone in a string and not a full string.

Comment: please check the links i sent you and add `12345-` also `only if it's alone in a string` what does it mean?

Comment: @Jerry down voting my answer, just because I'm identifying mistakes in yours??

Comment: And I'm not getting harsh nor wanted to get my answer upvoted neither get accepted. I just wanted you to correct the issues it has, that is why i asked you to compare it.

Comment: @zzlalani It's okay. I finally made up a PHP script (I'm not sure why JS won't print the resulting array with `string.match()`. See the [demo](http://viper-7.com/1CSvmE).

Comment: ohh i got it, `if a zip code exists within a string` i miss that part.. he wants to find zip with in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is

```
\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36kv8).

An important part here are the [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, they ensure that not a part of a number is matched.

`\d{5}` is matching 5 digits as you already had it

`(?:-\d{4})?` is the optional part (because of the `?` **after** the the group). The `?:` at the start of the group is just making the [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) non-capturing.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your regex to allow the optional prefix:

```
preg_match_all("/\d{5}(\-\d{4})?/", $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented this in javascript

```
/^(\s*|\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)$/;
```